# Data Binding in Code Behind C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a quite simple question:

I have a  People property whose type is List< Person > and a Person has a Name and Surname.
I want to show the Name on my listBoxPerson and I want to make binding operations in code behind - don't want to use ItemsSource property-
Here is my code snippet:

```
Binding userBinding = new Binding();
        userBinding.Source =People;
        userBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Person.Name");
        listBoxPerson.SetBinding(ContentProperty, userBinding);
```

and here is my xaml code:

```
 < ListBox Height="303" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,108,0,0" Name="listBoxPerson" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" >

        < ListBox.Resources >
            < ObjectDataProvider x:Key="UserData" ObjectType="local:Person"/ >
        < /ListBox.Resources >
        < ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            < DataTemplate >
                < Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" ></Label  >
            < /DataTemplate >
        < /ListBox.ItemTemplate >
    < /ListBox >
```

this works when I write

```
listboxPerson.ItemsSource= People;
```

but there is nobody listed with the first given code. I am confused on how to solve this binding problem, and will be pleased with any help=)

Comment: I thought there was an answer but ı got a bit dissapointed when ı  saw that it was an edit...=)

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't really make any sense.

Is the idea that you're supposed to populate `ListBox.Items` in code instead of binding `ItemsSource` to a collection?  If so, there's no need to create a binding at all; your code-behind should look something like:

```
MyListBox.Items.AddRange(myCollection);
```

Is the idea that you're supposed to create the binding to the `Name` property in code instead of in XAML?  In that case, you need to find the `Label` object in the `DataTemplate` and create the binding on it.  It's hard to imagine circumstances under which that would be a good idea.

If you're asked, "Why do it this way?", saying, "Because I was told to" really isn't an answer.  You need to find out why you're being asked to do it this way.  Among other things, knowing the reason will help you understand the question you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the `ItemsSourceProperty` instead of the `ContentProperty` can you use that?